# How to remove last comma from exploded custom field names list

Tags: php, database

For each published post, I own a custom field containing a list of authors names.
I have exploded the names list, hyperlinked each of them, and separated the authors names by commas.
The problem is it's shown an additional comma after the latest name listed, and I'd like to remove it.
What should I do?

```
$value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'authors_names', true);
$value_array = explode(',', $value);
foreach ($value_array as $array) {
    $remove_space = str_replace(' ', '-', $array);
    $url = esc_url('http://mywebsite.com/authors/' . $remove_space);
    if ('' !== $url) {
        $display = esc_html($array);
        print"<a href='$url'>$display</a>";
    }
    {
        echo ',';
    };
}
```

Comment: Please format your code so that we can actually read it (it is currently on one line), and also show us clear input and output.

Comment: I don't know how to format code, I'm aware there must be an integrated tool to do so but I can't find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to keep track of the key of the array, and when it is 1 less than the length of the array, don't output the `,`:

```
$value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'authors_names', true);
$value_array = explode(',', $value);
$num_values = count($value_array);
foreach ($value_array as $key => $array) {
    $remove_space = str_replace(' ', '-', $array);
    $url = esc_url('http://mywebsite.com/authors/' . $remove_space);
    if ('' !== $url) {
        $display = esc_html($array);
        print"<a href='$url'>$display</a>";
    }
    if ($key < $num_values - 1) {
        echo ',';
    };
}
```

Comment: @Valor_ thanks - answer and question both read more easily now.